# How to fix Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting this error although my imports are fine.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Weather`.

My code looks like this:
**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Weather from './components/Weather';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Weather />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Weather.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

export default Weather = () => (
  <View style={styles.weatherContainer}>
    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Icon size={48} name="weather-sunny" color={'#fff'} />
        <Text style={styles.tempText}> Temperature </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Sunny</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Hurts the eyes!</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

I've checked previous answers, tried both with named and default exports, but still having the error. Thanks.

Comment: Check if `import Weather from './components/Weather';` is correct. Most likely the component isn't in this path.

Comment: Where is `styles` coming from?

Comment: @Neil, `style` is in the same file, just didn't post it in the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After several hours of banging my head against the wall I managed to debug, the error is related to this import (not the weather import):

`import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';`.
This should be a default import like this:
`import Icon from ...`